# PhantomJS crashes when using CasperJs to navigate between frames

Tags: unit-testing, coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having some problems dismissing a pop-up Iframe while using CasperJs to navigate. The code is simple...

```
    @.then ->
        @.click('#buttonCancel');
        @.withFrame 'InlineDialog_Iframe', ->
            @.waitForSelector('#buttonCancel');
            @.clickLabel('No, thanks');
```

But every time I run this I get a error from phantomjs saying:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/4fd2a861-e967-d32e-1ae744f2-175a5f93.dmp
```

I can copy and paste the dump file here, but I don't know how much useful information there is in it.

It seems like every time I try and traverse between frames... phantom js crashes! Does anyone have any experience with this?

EDIT: Console output from running the app:

```
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/13: done in 16574ms.
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 11/13 https://--------- (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: xpath selector: //*[text()="No, thanks"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: xpath selector: //*[text()="No, thanks"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: xpath selector: //*[text()="No, thanks"]
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 11/13: done in 16687ms.
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new with the crash dump file attached:
```

Comment: Usually this is not a problem, have you tried to use JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript?

Comment: No such luck with JS eigther.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so this is unanswerable without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm looking around and it appears to be a bug with phantomjs - it crashes when you click on a button in an iframe that closes the iframe itself. this question may not be answerable.  https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11702

Comment: That might be it. I just noticed something. `clickLabel` is synchronous, but `waitForSelector` is not. So `clickLabel` has to be executed in the `waitForSelector` callback or inside of `then`.

Comment: I gave it a go and put .clicklabel under a "then". I'll add the console output to the question.